# Copying From Windows to NFS: Can The Timestamps Be Preserved?

Tags: windows, linux, unix, nfs, date

We have a Linux server that has NFS shares. Some Windows hosts (XP & 7) connect to it via Services for UNIX. I've been told the behavior is different from XP to 7 in terms of file creation dates when copying files.

Copy from Windows XP to Linux: File attributes show today's date.
Copy from Windows 7 to Linux: File shows original file timestamp.

I'm not sure why this is different depending on the version of Windows used. We would like consistent behavior regardless of XP or 7. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible.  There has been lots of changes Windows since Windows XP.

Comment: Linux doesn't have "creation date".

Comment: I meant the date time stamp on the file that shows up when you do "ls -l"